# How can I use log4j to log why RMI is failing

Tags: java, log4j, rmi

I am currently using log4j to log on both server and client side processes.
But I am having an rmi failure.
I would like to know if the problem is on the client side or the server side.
How can I use log4j to show me the rmi activity on both the client and server?
Note that I don't see any rmi logging.

My log4j file contains this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, Socket_Logger, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/log/RDS.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p (%t)[%c] %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG
```

The server log4j log shows things like:

```
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
```

But the Client side log doesn't show anything

Comment: please show your code and your stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Log4J has nothing to do with it. RMI uses Java logging. What you need to do is enable the client-side logging you need, via the [RMI system `logLevel` properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html).